# Magento 1.9.2.1 includes patch SUPEE-6482 but version is still 1.9.1.1

Tags: magento-1.9

There is no downloader for Magento 1.9.2.1 so I installed the full downloaded version 1.9.2.1 named magento-1.9.2.1-2015-08-03-06-33-36.zip on 30 Aug. 2015

But after installation (upgrade for database 1.5) this is version 1.9.1.1 and you get a notification CORRECTION for patch 6482

Is this a mistake from the Magento team ?

Edit: When I login Magento Connector I see on each installed core module 1.9.2.1, so it is only the wrong version on the admin page (1.9.1.1) .. that’s all !

Comment: No a mistake from me, the patch is installed but the version does not change to 1.9.2.1., the version is just 1.9.1.1. so can be a mistake, I reported to Magento team but a low chance I get an answer (many many emails ..)

Comment: I got an answer from the Magento team within 1 day, they look now to the version problem!

Comment: When installing a new version the version will be 1.9.2.1. in admin (and database), when you do an upgrade (I did from 1.5) the version stays 1.9.1.1 in my case (this is difficult to test by the Magento team of course, so probably no responce anymore) ..

Comment: app/mage.php is the onliest place where the version number have stored, so I changed this to 1.9.2.2 by myself (latest patch 6788 also installed) ..